# Pausing execution until other animations are complete jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dialog, rendering

I have several dialogs that open as follows:

```
  $("#dialog").load("/ajax/content.php");
  $("#dialog").dialog({....});
```

and a global event monitor to animate the dialog's opening

```
 $(document).on("dialogOpen", ".dialogClass", function() {
     var parent = $(this).parent();
     parent.css("left","-768px");
     parent.animate({
             left:0
     }, speed, "easeOutBounce");
 }
```

On some pages this is appearing pretty choppy.  I suspect that these animations are happening as the dialog is loading and rendering the results of its ajax call.  Is there any way I can pause until all other animations are complete such as:

```
 $(document).on("dialogOpen", ".dialogClass", function() {
     //Wait until other rendering is complete prior to executing further
     var parent = $(this).parent();
     parent.css("left","-768px");
     parent.animate({
             left:0
     }, speed, "easeOutBounce");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [jQuery .queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)?

Check out it out at: http://api.jquery.com/queue/

With this you can build a specific queue order you would like your animations to follow

Answer (score 0):

may be jquery callback functionality will help..

call the function that you want to execute after all other rendering is complete.. like

a simple example to show the alert after the action is complete

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide("slow",function(){
      somefunction(); // this will execute after the completion of function
    });
  });
});

somefunction()
{
alert("The paragraph is now hidden"); 
}
```